# Generating all pairs of numbers which XOR is N

Tags: bit-manipulation, computer-science

I need to find the way to generate all pairs (A,B), such that A<=10^5, B<=10^5, N<=10^5 and A XOR B == N. N is given as input.

I know solution that is in square time, with checking all values in two fors, but I think that there is faster solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
for A = 0 to 65536 do /* 65536 > 10^5 / 2 */
    B = A xor N
    if A <= 100000 and B <= 100000
        print A, B
        print B, A
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: That can produce some values of B greater than 10^5 even if N <= 10^5 and A <= 10^5. e.g. A = 81920, B = 114688, N = 32768. Add a check that B is <= 10^5 before outputting it.

Comment: Yeah, thank you the hint. I've added a condition for this case. I thought about that. I've also added a modification for using the symmetry of the pairs of solution. This decreases the number of steps for the loop.